Sum Column Not Reflecting Filtered Data in AppSheet
I am facing an issue with a table in my AppSheet application. I have a column called "Weight" and another column that calculates the sum of the "Weight" values for all the rows. However, the sum is being calculated for all the rows regardless of any filters applied. I need the sum to be calculated only for the filtered data.
Below is the screenshot of the query I have used and the table:
image
image
Can anyone help me with a solution to calculate the sum of the "Weight" column based on the filtered data?
Thanks in advance!
I tried using a sum query to calculate the total weight, but it currently sums the "Weight" values for all rows, ignoring any filters. I was expecting the sum to reflect only the filtered rows in the view.
